# Insert a row based on length of the string in cell

Tags: excel, macros, vba

How could i insert a row based on the row value for example
I have the following cases in the cells

```
SFF465
SFF465+466
SFF466+467+468+469
SFF469+DFG234
DFG235
DFG236+237+238+239
```

If there are or more values in the same cell i want to insert a new row for second batch. For example in first row there should not be any change but in second row both the batches need to split in different rows.I need `SFF465` in second row and `SFF 466` in third row.Thus the second row will change from `SFF465+466` to `SFF465` only.

Same thing goes for Current third row which has four numbers and want to split them individually as `SFF466`, `SFF467`, `SFF468`, `SFF469` below the current rows.

In the fourth row you can see, two different products. I want to split the by adding another row right below the current fourth row. Hence converting current Fourth row to `SFF469` and fifth row as `DFG234`.

Desired format would be

```
SFF465
SFF465
SFF466
SFF466
SFF467
SFF468
SFF469
SFF469
DFG234
DFG235
DFG236
DFG237
DFG238
DFG239
```

Thanks in advance.

I have written code using relative references and modifying them using `If Then` and `Do While` loops.

```
Sub Vcpy() 
' ' Vcpy Macro

    If ActiveCell.Value <> Empty Then 

        Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty

         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select 
         Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove    
         ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 4).Range("A1").Select
         Selection.Copy
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Range("A1").Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste Application.CutCopyMode = False 
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Range("A1").Select

       Loop 

   End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: Here is not such a place just "give me code". Have you tried at first? Did you write any formula or VBA code?

Comment: @bzimor. I write codes using relative references and modifying them using IF and dowhile loops.`Sub Vcpy()
'
' Vcpy Macro
If ActiveCell.Value <> Empty Then
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 4).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Loop
End If
End Sub

Comment: ok, put your code in question context, if there is any error, then ask to troubleshoot

Comment: Please add your code to the question so it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to make your code work, but I have a different solution. Verified on your given example dataset.

```
Sub RowSplitter()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim str As String

    Set rng = Range("A1")

    Do While (rng.Value <> "")
        ' Determine if we need to split
        If Len(rng.Value) > 6 Then
            ' Split values into an array
            arr() = Split(rng.Value, "+")

            For i = 1 To UBound(arr())
                str = ""

                ' Insert row
                rng.Offset(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown

                ' Calculate string to insert from array
                If Len(arr(i)) < 4 Then str = Left(arr(0), 3)
                str = str & arr(i)

                ' Enter value from array
                rng.Offset(i).Value = str
            Next i

            rng.Value = arr(0)
        End If

        Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
    Loop
End Sub
```